# "Engage Your Players with Google Play Games Features" - how to do this

Tags: android, google-play-games

Leaderboards and Achievements are already present in my game.
Since June 2015 I'm seeing this Optimization Tip in the console:

[image: Screenshot]

[The documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/) doesn't say what "player engagement" means.

Does it refer to [Events and Quests](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/quests)?

Comment: They're talking about things like sending players notifications when its their turn etc. Player engagement = keeping them involved in your game.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that 'Events and Quests' is one of the component in that suggestion.

Most popular things are [Achievements](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/achievements) and [Leaderboards](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards) which you can implement for player engagement.

[image: Achievement] [image: LeaderBoard]